# How to capture and send error with Go APM to Elastic Kibana?

Tags: go, elasticsearch, kibana, apm

I got the basics of Elastic and Kibana (version 8.4) APM for a simple go app, but I can't seem to populate the errors page when I go to `Kibana>Observability>APM>Services>MyGoApp>Errors`. It always looks empty like this:

[image]

The Overview page properly shows things though like this:
[image]

This is my golang code, any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Why don't errors show up in my Kibana APM Errors?

```
package main

import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        "github.com/joho/godotenv"
        "go.elastic.co/apm"
        "go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmhttp/v2"
)

func main() {
        godotenv.Load()
        router := mux.NewRouter()
        router.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
        router.HandleFunc("/error", errorPage)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", apmhttp.Wrap(router))

}
func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the HomePage!")
        fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}
func errorPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sending Error!")
        apm.CaptureError(r.Context(), errors.New("test error")).Send()
}
```

---

As experiment, I tried using `CaptureError()` method in nodejs. And it actually populated the errors.  This was my code:

```
var apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start({

  // Allowed characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _, and space
  serviceName: 'app2',

  // Use if APM Server requires a secret token
  secretToken: 'testtoken',
  serverUrl: 'http url',
  verifyServerCert: false,
  environment: 'production'
})

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3030

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/error', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Send Err!')
  const err = new Error('Trigger Error!')

  apm.setTransactionName('/error')
  apm.captureError(err)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

So it seems that `CaptureError()` works for nodejs package, but not for golang package.

Comment: what is the version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: @sagarpatel It is version 8.4

Comment: Can you change the date filter from top which is currently `Last 15 minitues` to `Last 7 days` and check if you are able to see or not.

Comment: No errors showed up in last 7 days either. I updated my question by saying i did an experiment with nodejs `CaptureError()`, and it worked for nodejs.  `CaptureError()` just doesn't seem to work for golang.

Comment: where you have defined apm in your go code?

Comment: Can you please check APM and Elasticsearch logs when you are running yout GO code and make sure that there is no Error available.

Comment: oh i thought `apm` was a statically typed class and you just run its methods.  I'll try to check documentation again.   I checked all logs and no errors coming from my GO code.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, I had to set the ELASTIC_APM_CAPTURE_BODY=all environment variable.
Otherwise the context you pass as the first argument is empty of any trace,
If either argument is nil then the error will not be returned.